# Embedded web server

Tags: embedded, arm, texas-instruments

I am working on a college project in which I want to embed a http web server on a TIVA launchpad eval board. I have been looking through the internet for any guidance on the subject but the information seems to be scarce. I have managed to try a custom mongoose server on a linux machine. During this process I served a single html file. I noticed that I have to supply a http port and directory to which my html file resided. To my understanding, ports are provided by a an OS and a directory can be implemented with a file system.

Do I need to use an operating system on this project in case I decide to go with mongoose web server? How do I implement the file system?

I also found another guide to use uIP. This guide was implemented with freeRTOS. I have a working knowledge of freeRTOS. Can I use uIP with no OS?

Kindly shed some light on the subject or point me towards the right direction.

Comment: Choosing a different Stack may help...

Comment: There don't have to be any file systems involved. A web server does nothing more than receiving lines of text through a TCP socket and sending back lines of text through that same TCP socket in response. Please check out how simple the HTTP protocol works before anything else.

Comment: UDP polling to port 80 can be like a dumb terminal but then without IRQ and no  embedded boot OS, simple tasks are made hard. So uIP (micro IP) and lwIP (lightweight IP) are both candidates  that  I think are BSD derived

Comment: Do you really want such a primitive interface prone to DoS attacks and IoT security issues?  Scarce? then you are looking for the wrong key words.  try Contiki OS

Comment: @Rufusy: Please capitalise proper names and initialisations correctly for clarity. There is an edit link under your post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference demo with a web server for this dev kit http://www.ti.com/tool/EK-TM4C1294XL

The software pack you have to look for is SW-EK-TM4C1294XL.